# Reopen a question closed as a duplicate of 3 different ones?

Tags: discussion, support

So [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093752/how-to-make-sure-im-not-using-any-proprietary-software-after-installation) has been closed as a duplicate of 3 different questions and their answers, but IMHO none of them *really answer the original question: **they're just related...***

*Is it appropriate to reopen that (highly upvoted) question?*

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I answered that question so not voting myself as that feels too much like a conflict of interest.</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Five users voted and the question was reopened.

I think you should vote to reopen even when you’re biased. It’s a good idea to add a comment for reviewers explaining why you think the question should be reopened, how dupes don’t match etc.

Asking on meta certainly brings attention to the question and your endeavor, but it is a bit much: A VTR which puts it in the review queue should rather be the way to approach the simple question “Should we reopen this or not?”, especially if you don’t need to raise points not fitting into a comment on the question.

#### For users under 3000 reputation

Even if you haven’t gained the privilege to cast reopen votes yet there are several things you can do:

- Edit the question (directly or through a suggestion) and clarify why it is not a duplicate
  An edit on a closed question automatically places it in the reopen queue where it’s considered for reopening by reviewers.
- Ask a question on Meta
  This is the right thing to do if you’re not sure about an edit. Include all information, especially why you think it isn’t a duplicate.
- Ask in chat
  Many experienced users and mods hang out in [the Ask Ubuntu General Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room), you’re welcome to join and ask about things like that.

Comment: That's useful advice for those who have sufficient reputation to vote to reopen. But what should users who don't have that much reputation do? I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/919441/284919) which is also marked as a duplicate without actually being one. I have added a comment, but on it's own that's not likely to get the question reopened. Even if I could cast a reopen vote it's unlikely the reviewers would see my comment among all the others.

Comment: @kasperd see edit :)

Comment: @kasperd Related: [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415)